# mac pc local site netbois ipaddress

Tags: configuration, ip-address, local

There's a local site on my PC, it's using `192.168.1.103`, my macbook is using `192.168.1.104`, I can access the site by IP, but macbook can't access the site by netbios.

Comment: This does not fit on ServerFault, due to the fact that it is some kind of development setup, not a professional one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is fake a DNS entry by editing /etc/hosts on the Mac. Open Terminal and do

```
 sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Then add a line

```
 192.168.1.103 your.site.domain
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use DHCP, I am afraid I need to change the hosts file when the ip changes.

Comment: To prevent this you can bind the MAC address to a fixed IP, this way it will never change. Also check if your router has DNS capabilities, this way you can have a hostname without modifying /etc/host